# Rewrite Regla para URL amigables de parametros

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, get, rewriterule

Como están, no soy programador profesional, estoy aprendiendo. Compré una plantilla de Wordpress que me da algunas URL de filtrado de búsqueda no amigables y me gustaría modificarlas. Estuve buscando y llegué a la Regla Rewrite que podría llegar a ser mi solución.

Las url de mi proyecto son de la siguiente manera proyectoejemplo.com/houses/?region=264

Mientras que me gustaría que devuelva el valor de "texto" de la región, por ejemplo a mi me gustaría así:

proyectoejemplo.com/houses/california

Probé agregando al archivo htaccess el siguiente código pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^houses/(.+)$ region=$1
</IfModule>
```

Espero su ayuda, recompenso con café y mate :D

Gracias

Comment: Las urls amigables se pueden configurar desde el mismo wordpress sin necesidad de modificar el htaccess, ve a ajustes -> enlaces permanentes y selecciona el nombre de post y actualiza, con eso deberia de salir de forma amigable.

Comment: Hola Jefferzon, como estás? Gracias por tu respuesta, no puedo hacerlo de esa forma ya que es una plantilla tema "inmobiliario" comprada que genera urls cuando seleccionamos diferentes parametros en el buscador interno, como "Region", "cantidad de baños", "precio". Por lo tanto busco hacer mas amigables esas URL a través del código.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó agregar el *houses*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^houses/(.+)$ houses/?region=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hola Cesar! puse el código como me dijiste pero aún así no me reescribe la URL, te muestro para que veas, capaz estoy haciendo algo mal: https://www.realestatebuyandrent.com/houses/?region=252